# Dropdown cascade of interlocked items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to do a drop-down cascade with dependent choice, like here     http://jsfiddle.net/6eCZC/1/.

But I have a table which items are in a part of a part of a table.

Like this:

```
$scope.option = [
{id: 1, name: "WebSite", 
  countries: [{id: 1, name: "Country", 
    servers: [{id: 1, name: "Server1"}, 
      {id: 2, name: "Server2"},
      {id: 3, name: "Server3"}]}]}];
  $scope.selectedRequest = {};
  $scope.selectedRequest.option = $scope.option[0];
```

and my HTML

```
 <select name="site" ng-model="selectedRequest.site" ng-options="site.name for site in option" required></select>
<select name="country" ng-model="selectedRequest.country" ng-options="country.name for country in selectedRequest.option.countries">
 </select>
<select name="server" ng-model="selectedRequest.server" ng-options="server.name for server in selectedRequest.option.countries.servers">
  </select>
```

It works for the site and the country but not for the servers.

Comment: can you please make fiddle of your own attempt and put some more options data to check which you are testing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tjp6q0gb/

Comment: Please edit your fiddle and put server objects data.It only have countries.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tjp6q0gb/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use previously selected object's content when you are selecting.

Here is the working code (with some new options):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.option = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "WebSite",
    countries: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Switzerland",
      servers: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Sw Server1"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Sw Server2"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "Sw Server3"
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Hungary",
      servers: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Hu Server1"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Hu Server2"
      }]
    }]
  }];

  $scope.selectedRequest = {};
  $scope.selectedRequest.option = $scope.option[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <select name="site" ng-model="selectedRequest.site" ng-options="site.name for site in option" required></select>
    <select name="country" ng-model="selectedRequest.country" ng-options="country.name for country in selectedRequest.site.countries"></select>
    <select name="server" ng-model="selectedRequest.server" ng-options="server.name for server in selectedRequest.country.servers"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Best,
Peter

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but I have two Website, and when I select a website + a country + a server and then I change the website, the country disappear but not the server. How can I reset it ?